# Google Identity Services using the token model - Is initTokenClient / requestAccessToken returning the correct scopes?

Tags: google-oauth

I'm migrating a web app to the new Google Identity Services API and trying to implement granular scope authorization following this guide:
[Using the token model : Granular permissions](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model#granular_permissions)

The guide states:

> Any previously accepted grants from prior sessions or requests will also be included in the response

However, this doesn't seem to work as expected - in situations where only one of two requested scopes are previously granted, I either get both scopes returned or no token at all, depending on how the user responds to the prompt.

[This app](https://visual-planner.github.io/vp.htm) demonstrates the problem - the Settings page shows which permissions have been granted.

On the first visit, Google's pop-up UX lists the requested permissions enabling the user to choose which ones to grant. If they choose only one of the two, the returned token correctly includes the corresponding scope.

On subsequent visits, the pop-up only lists the permission not granted the first time. Continuing will grant both permissions, cancelling will result in no token returned for either scope. Is this correct? I would have expected that having requested both scopes, I would always get at least the granted scope returned.

If the subsequent pop-ups included a permission check-box as is the case initially, the user would be able to continue using the app without granting the second permission. As it is, there is no UX flow available which allows this.

```
var permissions = {};

function loadPermissions() {
    google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
        prompt: "",
        callback: rcv
    }).requestAccessToken();

    function rcv(tok) {
        if (google.accounts.oauth2.hasGrantedAllScopes(tok, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"))
            permissions.view_calendars = true;

        if (google.accounts.oauth2.hasGrantedAllScopes(tok, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"))
            permissions.drive_appdata = true;
    }
}
```